# How to auto load last submission (single submission)?

Tags: forms, drupal, submission, drupal-webform

I built multiple webforms in Drupal. I want user to

- Submit only ONE submission by form.
- Auto load last submission when they go again on webform submitted.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You could use the email webform component, set it as `unique` and check the `User email as default`, if you'd have one in your webform.
- Autoloading a webform submission might be possible with by creating a views block with a contextual filters to the user giving the uid provided & a relation to webform.

As you might not want an additional webform component for your webforms (or not all of them), you could always create a module, include the webform functionality and retrieve the submitted data on a webform instance with `hook_form_alter()` as:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    // get current user
    global $user;

    // include webform functionality
    module_load_include('inc','webform','includes/webform.submissions');

    // make sure to only alter webform forms
    if (strpos($form_id, 'webform_client_form_') !== FALSE) {

        // check if the user is a an authenticated user
        if (in_array('authenticated user', $user->roles)) {

            // build $filters array for submission retrieval
            $filters = array(
                'nid' => $form['#node']->webform['nid'],
                'uid' => $user->uid,
            );

            /** 
             * When not using a unique webform component for 1 submission
             * you can use a submission of the user on a webform instance
             * to prevent another submission.
             */

            // get submissions of the user by webform nid
            if ($submissions = webform_get_submissions($filters)) {

                // disable the form to limit multiple submissions per instance
                $form['#disabled'] = TRUE;

                /**
                 * Webform instance submission data of the current user
                 * can be found in $submissions[1]->data array
                 */

                # render your submission with Form api
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting to only 1 submission per webform can be done via Webform -> Form Settings -> Total Submissions Limit and Per User submission limit as shown in this screenshot

[image]
To autoload user submission, since above would not allow you to show the webform would be via using the submission id of the webform they already submitted. Based on this [code](https://nasireee.wordpress.com/tag/drupal-webform-get-submissions/)

```
module_load_include('inc','webform','includes/webform.submissions');
$sid = 10;
$submission = webform_get_submissions(array('sid' => $sid));
$nid = $submission[$sid]->nid;

$web_submission = webform_get_submission($nid, $sid);
$node = node_load($nid);
$output = webform_submission_render($node, $web_submission, NULL, 'html');

print $output;
```